# C# - can you name a matrix with the contents of a string

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

Basically I have x amount of matrices I need to establish of y by y size. I was hoping to name the matrices: matrixnumber1 matrixnumber2..matrixnumbern

I cannot use an array as its matrices I have to form.

Is it possible to use a string to name a string (or a matrix in this case)?

Thank you in advance for any help on this!

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberofmatricesrequired; i++)
        {
        string number = Convert.ToString(i);
        Matrix (matrixnumber+number) = new Matrix(matrixsize, matrixsize);
        }
```

Comment: Why can't you use an array? What's wrong with Matrix [] matrixArray = new Matrix[numberofmatricesrequired] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve a similar effect by creating an `array` of Matrices and storing each `Matrix` in there.

For example:

```
Matrix[] matrices = new Matrix[numberofmatricesrequired];
for (int i = 0; i < numberofmatricesrequired; i++)
{
    matrices[i] = new Matrix(matrixsize, matrixsize);
}
```

This will store a bunch of uniques matrices in the `array`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. 

I tried that initially but I received an error "Index was outside the bounds of the array". So I thought an array of matrices was not possible?

Comment: @RHodgett That was probably because you were going from 1 up to the max.  You need to go from 0 to the max-1.

Comment: Brilliant it worked! The problem was I was starting the loop from 0 

"for (int i = 0; i <= (Matrices.Length-1); i++)"

Worked Fine! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to you could create a `Dictionary<String, Matrix>` to hold the matrices you create. The string is the name - created however you like.

You can then retrieve the matrix by using `dict["matrix1"]` (or whatever you've called it).

However an array if you have a predetermined number would be far simpler and you can refer to which ever you want via it's index:

```
Matrix theOne = matrix[index];
```

If you have a variable number a `List<Matrix>` would be simpler and if you always added to the end you could still refer to individual ones by its index.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious why you cannot use an array or a `List`, as it seems like either of those are *exactly* what you need.

```
Matrix[] matrices = new Matrix[numberofmatricesrequired];

for (int i = 0; i < matrices.Length; i++)
{
    matrices[i] = new Matrix(matrixsize, matrixsize);
}
```

If you really want to use a string, then you could use a `Dictionary<string, Matrix>`, but given your naming scheme it seems like an index-based mechanism (ie. array or `List`) is better suited. Nonetheless, in the spirit of being comprehensive...

```
Dictionary<string, Matrix> matrices = new Dictionary<string, Matrix>();

for (int i = 1; i <= numberofmatricesrequired; i++)
{
    matrices.Add("Matrix" + i.ToString(), new Matrix(matrixsize, matrixsize));
}
```